# check variable value from host_vars null or not

Tags: ansible

I have defined a variable in host_vars/hostname.yml with no value assigned to it. I have the below task defined to check if the variable is empty. My play should fail.

host_vars/hostname.yml

```yaml
tls_password:
```

```yaml
- name: Check for null
  fail: msg="Error value is null"
  when: tls_password == ""
```

When I run this task it is getting skipped. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The variable *tls_password* is not an empty string. It is YAML `None` equivalent of Python `null`

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: tls_password|type_debug
```

gives

```yaml
    tls_password|type_debug: NoneType
```

Therefore the comparison

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: '{{ tls_password == "" }}'
```

will evaluate to `false` and your task will  be skipped

```yaml
    msg: false
```

The solution is simple. Test the `None` value

```yaml
    - name: Check for null
      fail:
        msg: Error value is null
      when: tls_password == None
```

gives what you want

```yaml
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: Error value is null
```

Comment: Thank you now i can see error message in case of empty variable in vars or host_vars.